# Connections on a Baby Orangutang B-328 board

Tags: microcontroller

I am new to robotics and planning my first purchase.
I'm looking at the Baby Orangutang B-328. Here is information about the microcontroller: http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/baby-orangutan-328.

The pin headers come unmounted, so you have to do the soldering yourself. My problem is that I don't know what the pin connections are for. Here is a picture of the board:

http://www.ca.diigiit.com/image/cache/data/pololu/1220/Pololu-Baby-orangutan-b-328-6-500x500.png.

Could someone briefly tell me what the different connections are for, or link a website that does?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* Eijomjo, but sadly "How do I use" questions are far too broad to make a good Stack Exchange question. We prefer [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Feel free to come back again and ask more specific Robotics questions once you have read the [Baby Orangutan B Users Guide](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/datasheets/baby_orangutan_b.pdf). For more general electronics questions however, you would be better off asking on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I will certainly keep that in mind for future posts. And thanks for the advice!

Comment: No problem Eijomjo, I always hate closing questions by newcomers to the site, I want people to feel welcome here and I try to avoid putting people off. Ultimately keeping the questions on topic and the quality of questions and answers high will make the site more useful in the long run. I look forward to seeing your future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the bottom of the page on your first link:  http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/baby-orangutan-328. under "Documents relating to the Baby Orangutan B-328".

There you will find links to the [Baby Orangutan B Users Guide](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/datasheets/baby_orangutan_b.pdf) as well as other useful links.

The user's guide contains the pin descriptions you need on page 5.